# Receiving a PUBLISH message that contains QoS of 0 but has a Message ID

Tags: mqtt

I'm working on an M2M application using MQTT (in C#, though I can't see how that would matter).  I've published a message up to the broker with a `QoS` of 1 and the `RETAIN` bit ON.  When I subsequently subscribe to the topic (subscribing with a `QoS` of 0), I receive back a PUBLISH message andthe header says it has a `QoS` of 0.

The problem I'm running into is that the variable header for the topic contains a Message ID, but I have no way to programmatically know it's there.  The spec seems to indicate that the MessageID should only be present when a `QoS` or 1 or 2 is set, but my byte 0 of the incoming packet is clearly 0x31 (Message type of `PUBLISH`, `QoS` of 0, `RETAIN` = 1).

Right now my workaround is to to deserialize the data and if I get an exception, I jump forward two bytes and try again.  That works, but it sure feels kludgey to me.

Is this expected behavior?  A problem with the broker I'm using?  Some misunderstanding of the spec on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're saying something certainly doesn't seem right. It's not expected behaviour nor a misunderstanding of the spec. There should never be a message id in a QoS 0 message.

What broker are you using? Could you try your code against the broker at test.mosquitto.org:1883 and see if it behaves the same? Likewise if an existing client (like mosquitto_sub from http://mosquitto.org/download/ ) has problems then it's not you that is at fault.

Comment: I'm using Eurotech's Everware Device Cloud broker.  Smells like a bug then.  I'm pretty new to MQTT so I didn't want to throw out the bug flag so early.

Comment: which C# client library are you using? Have you tried the same code against test.mosquitto.org or m2m.eclipse.org?